# How and where to format date in Django (Python, Ajax)?

Tags: python, ajax, django

Can I format the date in the foreach loop ?

```
advertisements_list = []
    for advertisement in advertisements:
         advertisements_list.append({
            'id': advertisement.id, 
            'description': advertisement.description,
            'title': advertisement.title,
            'picture_url': advertisement.image.url,
            'date': advertisement.date -> format that })
```

In my template I would do something like `{{ advertisement.date | date:"d.m.Y" }}`. Is there something similiar which I can use in my foreach-loop ? I can not go the template way because it is Ajax.

Is it even the right place for formatting or should I do the formatting with JavaScript/jQuery when I passed the data ?

Comment: either way is acceptable ... since your already looping over it here to create the dictionaries its pretty easy to just add a strftime to get a formatted datestring. if you are using ajax i would strongly recommend a format that javascript can parse simply with the Date directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
'date': advertisement.date.strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the first answer, what you can do is to add a method to the advertisement class which returns a properly formatted date (and there are a few ways to achieve that). Call it "formattedDate" for example. Then the code fragment you provided will become much cleaner.